# writing this symbols in LaTeX

Tags: latex

I am trying to write this symbols ( < and > ) in a text in LaTeX but I got rare characters. How can I do it?

Comment: What encoding are you using? Usually, they will compile with LaTeX just fine

Comment: This explains what's happening and how to solve it: [Why do the less than symbol (`<`) and the greater than symbol (`>`) appear wrong as upside down exclamation (`¡`) or question mark (`¿`)?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/2369/5764)

Answer (score 2):

`$>$` and `$<$` should do the trick, if you don't mind sneaking in math mode.

Comment: ...but could look ugly if math mode changes fonts or spacing.

Comment: If you do mind sneaking in math mode, you can use `\textless` and `\textgreater`.